# How can I convert a text node to a string in Go with Gokogiri?

Tags: go, gokogiri

For my first programming attempt with Go I'm trying to automate the downloading of the lovely wallpapers from [Psiu Puxa](http://psiupuxa3.webflow.io/), saving the images with filenames based on titles in the posts in the HTML.

However, I haven't found how to get the value of a text node as a string.

Example HTML, simplified:

```
<div class="post">
    <a class="w-inline-block post-name-link" href="/posts/mars-30">
        <h4>#80 Martian Landscape</h4>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="post">
    <a class="w-inline-block post-name-link" href="#">
        <h4><strong>#79 MARTIAN terrain</strong></h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

My Go package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
)

func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://psiupuxa3.webflow.io/")
    page, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

    doc, _ := gokogiri.ParseHtml(page)
    res, _ := doc.Search("//div[@class='post']")
    defer doc.Free()

    for i := range res {
        postTitleRes, _ := res[i].Search("a[contains(@class,'post-name-link')]//text()")
        fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", postTitleRes, postTitleRes)
    }

}
```

Result:

```
[]xml.Node: [#80 Martian Landscape]
[]xml.Node: [#79 MARTIAN terrain]
[]xml.Node: [#78 MARTIAN TERRAIN]
```

How can I obtain `#79 MARTIAN terrain`, etc., as strings for later use when saving files?

I've tried `postTitle := postTitleRes.String()` but the method apparently isn't available for `xml.Node`. I've spent some time looking through Gokogiri's source code and have found methods/instructions on coercing to strings, but I'm quite lost and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery ? maybe is a good alternative to what you try to achieve. It def. is easier to use.

Comment: I have, but having got this far with gokogiri I'd prefer to find out how to do the last bit and convert to string. Plus I'd like to know how to use XPath for real projects in future. But thanks - I'll keep that alternative in mind.

Comment: Sure, understandable. What does `postTitleRes[0]` returns?

Comment: It returns a `*xml.TextNode`, which I *can* call `String()` on! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an array of xml.Node structs there. You would need to access the nodes contained in that array.

If you're sure you have one element then you can

```
postTitleRes[0].Content()
```

or to capture all of those nodes:

```
for _, node := range postTitleRes {
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", node, node.Content())
}
```

You can see that the `Content` function should be available to you once you have a singular xml.Node. [Definition](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/blob/master/xml/node.go#L848).